# Как написать запрос с помощью ActiveRecord

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Как написать на ActiveRecord запрос такого вида `select id, field1 + field2 + field3  AS sum from table where id = '1'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите пример в [документации](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#selecting-extra-fields):

```php
class Room extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $volume;

    // ...
}

$rooms = Room::find()
    ->select([
        '{{room}}.*', // select all columns
        '([[length]] * [[width]] * [[height]]) AS volume', // calculate a volume
    ])
    ->orderBy('volume DESC') // apply sort
    ->all();

foreach ($rooms as $room) {
    echo $room->volume; // contains value calculated by SQL
}
```